# Late Binding Vs Early Binding

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using late binding code by using excel 2016, however when the earlier versions tried opening my created excel file, missing reference will happen and i have to remove it every time.

I thought late binding not suppose to be happened that way? My code as below :

```
Private Sub NTStep2a_Click()
Dim ws As Object
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Entry (A)")
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Desktop\xxx"
objWord.ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:="xxx"
With objWord.ActiveDocument
objWord.ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="xxx", NoReset:=False, Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields
End With
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: The 'early versions' still have to have access to some version of the library reference.

Comment: Have you confirm your early binding to uncheck the reference of word?

Comment: which early binding u referring to @PaichengWu?

Comment: In VBE, press `ALT+T`, then `R`.  Make sure `Microsoft Word x.0 Object Library` is unchecked.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to uncheck every time they need to use my created excel file? Just because of that, it's quite troublesome as i actually locked the file. nobody is allow to unlock the file except me, and in order to uncheck it needs unlock. That is why I need to use late binding which I'm asking now, but at my case, late binding doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: _Does this mean that I have to uncheck every time they need to use my created excel file?_ No, it means that you have to open the file, uncheck the reference and save it. From now on it should open without problems in  'early versions'.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you refer to some version of library which is not available.

For example, you use `createObject("word.application.11")` to create `word`, but word version 11 is not available.

You could try omit the version number, e.g. `createObject("word.application")`.

Comment: Thanks, but i did not insert the version number. i did createobject("word.application")

Comment: @ChingLuTay if you had posted an example of your code in your original question then PaichengWu would not have wasted some time with a useful answer and probably been able to help you differently.